# Persistent settings for Play application

Tags: playframework-2.0, settings

I am developing an application which is a web administration console for another application.  One of my requirements is that the user can change some settings, such as the database url, and persist them.

Is it possible to use play configuration in Write mode too ? If not, what is the simplest solution to implement this without a database, since we are talking about 4-5 string settings?

Answer (score 0):

Play allows you to make your own implementation for the models layer. You can implement your own means of persistence. If you do not want to use a database, you could persist to a file, for example.

In this case you could write model classes to match different modules or functionalities in the application you want to provide implementation for. If you want to persist some data locally without a database, you can create a model to persist info to a text file or other means you choose.